# FFmpeg - Convert MP4 to Webm very slow

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, libvpx

I need convert MP4 to webm with ffmpeg.
So, i use :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

But it's very long.

Is there faster ?

Comment: What is the length of your `mp4` video?

Comment: Between 100Mo and 1000Mo

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270625/how-to-fast-convert-mp4-to-webm-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 11):

libvpx is a relatively slow encoder. According to the [VP8 Encode Parameter Guide: Encode Quality vs. Speed](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/#2-encode-quality-vs-speed), you can use the `-cpu-used` option to increase encoding speed. A higher value results in faster encoding but lower quality:

> Setting a value of 0 will give the best quality output but is
>   extremely slow. Using 1 (default) or 2 will give further significant
>   boosts to encode speed, but will start to have a more noticeable
>   impact on quality and may also start to effect the accuracy of the
>   data rate control. Setting a value of 4 or 5 will turn off "rate
>   distortion optimisation" which has a big impact on quality, but also
>   greatly speeds up the encoder.

Alternatively, it appears that VA-API can be utilized for hardware accelerated VP8 encoding, but I have no experience with this.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! But is there no an other encoder that libvpx ? A faster encoder ?

Comment: @Luzwitz For VP8, I'm guessing your choices are libvpx or VA-API.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , I am facing an issue with stopping  video recording with ffmpeg.  I saw this answer [https://askubuntu.com/questions/436956/stop-the-recording-after-some-period-of-time]  for stopping after a peiod of time, and It worked fine . But I want to stop the recording after a button click . How can I do this? Please help

Comment: @Liya Use the button to issue `kill <ffmpeg pid>`. For related info see [Is there a way to pause and resume FFmpeg encoding?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17069/1760) I'm assuming you're using Linux since you didn't specify. If it's another OS you should ask a new question at [su] (or [so] if the question involves programming).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ya I am using Linux, I could'nt get the process id using **pgrep ffmpeg**  command, So I coudnt kill that process.